# Generate list of 200,000 hashes and save to file

Tags: python, while-loop

I wrote up this quick script to generate 200,000 hash random values and save them to a file, but I'm getting this error when I run the file: "`TypeError: expected a character buffer object`" on line: `file_.write(hash)`

```
import random

hash = random.SystemRandom()
file_ = open('output.txt', 'w')

count = 0

while count < 200000:
    file_.write(hash)

file_.close()
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: since you don't increment `count`, that's an infinite loop, and wouldn't write out 200,000 random values. it'd write out ONE value, an infinite number of times...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discover what you're doing wrong:

Open the interactive shell, type bits of your script:

```
>>> import random
>>>
>>> random.SystemRandom()
<random.SystemRandom object at 0x03FD83C8>
```

It's not a number, it's not text. You can't write it to a file.

Look at the docs:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom

It's a random number *generator*. You need to use it like `random`. Either `random.random()` or `random.randint(...)` or something.

And then convert those to text with `str(...)` before writing to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because hash is not a type that can be written to a file.  If you want to just get a certain number of bits of randomness, and write that to the file, you can do `hash.getrandbits(<number of bits>)`, although this gives you an integer as output.  Also, your loop does not terminate because you are not incrementing count.  I would recommend using a for loop instead.